# Why we can't compare a int variable with int return type function in c?

Tags: c, function

I tried to compare int variable with the function in two ways:

1. storing the int function return value in a variable then comparing with another 
   in value.
2. Directly comparing the int variable and the function call.

Here I got the answer for the first one but not for the second one.

Why does this happen?

My code:

```
#include < stdio.h >

int count = 0;
int countDigits(int);

int main() {

  int i;
  int result = countDigits(435);
  for (i = 0; i < result; i++) {

    printf("id %d\n", 3);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < countDigits(435); i++) {

    printf("i =%d\n", i);
  }
}

int countDigits(int n) {

  if (n == 0) {
    return count;
  } else {
    countDigits(n / 10);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what the function really returns, by for example printing the return value? Because it doesn’t return what you think it does.

Comment: Please post the output you get when you run the code, along with the expected output.

Comment: What does `countDigits` retun if `n` is different from 0?

Comment: Hint: my compiler tells me this:`'countDigits': not all control paths return a value`

Comment: Why are you using `count` as a global?

Comment: Are you aware that the loop condition is evaluated for each iteration and the function is called over and over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `count` is a global variable.
- The function `countDigits(n)` adds the number of decimal digits in *n* to `count` and

  - If *n* is zero it returns 1.
  - If *n* is non-zero the return value is undefined.

Since `countDigits(435)` has an undefined value, anything can happen and no further analysis is necessary.

Let's assume that this obvious error is corrected by inserting `return count;` after `count++;`. In this case, the function returns the incremented `count`.

- So we have this nice sequence:

  - Set `result` to `countDigits(435)`.

  `countDigits(435)` adds 3 to `count` and returns 3.

  - Set `i` to 0 and compare to `countDigits(435)`.

  `countDigits(435)` adds 3 to `count` and returns 6. 0 is less than 6, so the `for` loop continues.

  - Now `i` is 1, and we compare it to `countDigits(435)`.

  `countDigits(435)` adds 3 to `count` and returns 9. 1 is less than 9, so the `for` loop continues.

  - Now `i` is 2, and we compare it to `countDigits(435)`.

  `countDigits(435)` adds 3 to `count` and returns 12. 2 is less than 12, so the `for` loop continues.

... And so on.

Morality:

- Beware of side effects. Never use and modify global variables unless you have a good reason to.
- When you must use side effects, keep them prominent in your mind.

Comment: #Chux: You are right, and I was oblivious to the obvious error. I have edited the answer to highlight the error.

Answer (score 4):

We can.

It's just that your function has a logical error. Debug it, and you will be fine.

Enabling compiler warnings would have helped you. For example with GCC and Wall flag, you get:

```
prog.c: In function 'countDigits':
prog.c:32:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void 
function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Tip: Think of what your function does if `n` us different than zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to compare a variable directly with the output of a function. However, your function `countDigits` has several problems.

1. Not all code paths return a value - you're missing a `return` statement in the `else` block. This alone makes the output of the function undefined.
2. It's not algorithmically correct. Have you tried debugging it? Just start with printing the output for different inputs and you'll see.
3. Modifying and returning a global variable `count` inside that function is a really bad practice - it should be local to the function. When it's global, every call to the function modifies a [possibly] already modified variable.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already addressed the problem here with globals, so I will not go into details about that. Instead, here is a solution without globals:

```
int countDigits(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while(n>0) {
        n/=10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I guess you could be philosophical about whether `0` has 0 or 1 digit, but your code implied that you wanted it to be 0. If you want it to be 1 instead, just change the first row to `int count = 1`.